# go build command-line-arguments: open NUL: Can not find the specified file

Tags: go

I'm in trouble, when I try to launch any .go app I have this error:

```
C:\Go12\test>go run cmp.go
go build command-line-arguments: open NUL: Can not find the specified file.
```

```
C:\Go12\test>go env
set GOARCH=386
set GOBIN=C:\going\bin\
set GOCHAR=8
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=386
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\going\
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go12
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go12\pkg\tool\windows_386
set TERM=dumb
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-g -O2 -m32
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
```

What am I doing wrong? Hope for your help, thanks.

Comment: can you run `dir` for us?

Comment: The russian translates (roughly) to "File Not Found" for other people looking at this.

Comment: @cristopher-pfohl, http://pastebin.com/C99YkYGU

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `GOPATH` is set to `C:\going`, but your actual code is in `C:\Go12\test`. The `GOPATH` variable is supposed to be the root of your workspace, and your code should be in a subdirectory of `$GOPATH\src`.

Try putting your .go file in `C:\going\src\test` and try again. Also make sure that `cmp.go` says `package main` for its package declaration or `go run` won't work properly.

*In addition to the above*, make sure you're in the same directory as `cmp.go` when you use `go run`.

See [**How to write Go Code**](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) for more information on the Go workspace and environment variable setup.

Comment: It's just for tests. Apps from gopath can not be launched too. I've tried to launch helloworld from workspace, result is same.
C:\going\src>go run helloworld.go
go build command-line-arguments: open NUL: Can not find the specified file.

Comment: Hrmm... what exact directory was the helloworld program in? Usually the error that it can't find the file is related to a bad GOPATH setup. It could be something else, but that's usually the cause.

Comment: my file is in c:\going\src\

Comment: Try putting it in C:\going\src\hello. `src` is the "root level" as far as source code is concerned, it's not actually a valid location for code, only directories/packages.

Comment: Error is still here. I've tried to put .go files in random directories, to invoke Go from PATH or directrly. It just doesn't work and problem isn't in filepath.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove GOBIN environment variable.

Alex